# Variable defined on the $scope not updating until next cycle

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Here is a plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/PaG1k5N37BTOflObnN7K?p=preview

**Scenario 1**:

Step 1 - When "m" is entered in the `tags` input box, `Marie` is displayed as a suggestion.

Step 2 - When "j" is entered, `John` appears as a suggestion.

Step 3 - When "m" is entered again, there are no suggestions. I have implemented this functionality in `script.js`. This works perfectly as, `Marie` is being removed from `$scope.to` because it is already added to the `tags` input box in step 1.

**Scenario 2**:

Step 1 - When "m" is entered in the `tags` input box, `Marie` is displayed as a suggestion.

Step 2 - When "m" is entered again, `Marie` still appears as a suggestion.

So, until `John` or `Ghita` are entered in the `tags` input box, `Marie` keeps appearing as a suggestion. As soon as `John` is entered (e.g. the above scenario) `Marie` is not displayed as a suggestion anymore.

Does anyone have ideas as to why this behavior is caused?

I tried to use `$scope.$apply()`, but it gives me an error that says, a `$digest` cycle is already in progress. So, when `$scope.$digest()` is already executing, why is the `$scope.to` variable not getting updated?

Comment: I understand your description steps and what I should be seeing happen but in your plunker when I type the second m "mm" the Marie suggestion disappears correctly.

Comment: I think she means when you type "m", select "Marie", then type "m" again and "Marie" shows up once more. The intended behaviour is for "Marie" to not show up as a suggestion once it's been used already, hence removing it from `$scope.to`.

Comment: @bransonl That's exactly what I mean. Thanks.

Comment: @pierdevara Please take a look at `bransonl's` comment for a better understanding of the question. I have also edited my question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into an issue with the Typeahead library.  You will want to wrap your tag added callback in a `$timeout` call.

```
$scope.$on("decipher.tags.added", function(info, obj) {
  $timeout(function(){
    tagAdded(info, obj);
  });
});
```

Will fix the issue.  You can see that the angular-tags directive itself does this when filtering the internal tag list:

https://github.com/boneskull/angular-tags/blob/master/src/tags.js#L69

Edit:
Here's a [working fork](http://plnkr.co/edit/elPefHusJMunHEOhP0HI?p=preview) of your original Plunker.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the angular-tags library itself:
https://github.com/boneskull/angular-tags/issues/28

Looks like it's not being updated for versions of angular greater than 1.2.0-rc.2

Answer (score 0):

As stated by another user, it seems as though this is a bug with the current version of the tags you're using. A temporary workaround is to use `$compile` to update the tags in `tagAdded`. To use it, include `$compile` as a parameter in your `emailViewController` along with `$scope` and inject it as a dependency at the bottom along with `$scope`. After that, you can call

`$compile(document.getElementsByTagName("tags")[0])($scope);`

to update it. A side effect of this is that the input area loses focus each time a tag is added, which may or may not make a large impact in the usability of your app.

Refer to http://plnkr.co/edit/UVELXnrjOKasRnuGVA0e?p=preview for a demonstration of using `$compile`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a $timeout

```
$timeout(function(){//your code});
```

In angular $timeout forces your digest to update your variables, and it doesn't thrown a digest already in progress error.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
if(!$scope.$$phase) {
    $scope.$digest();
}
```

$scope.$$phase is a flag set to true while angular is in the $digest cycle

Comment: @Chris This is anti-pattern, you shouldn't use such a solutions. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Anti-Patterns